# FIlling a float array with a single value

Tags: c, arrays

```
#define WERT -0.01
```

here is my array:

```
 float name[9999];
```

I want to fill it with the value of WERT

I couldn't find a short way, and tried

```
 for (i = 1000; i <=9999 i+=1) {
      name[i] = WERT;
 }
```

but the program crashes. The loop is too long.

Any other way?

Comment: Following the zero indexing convention, the array covers indexes 0 to 9998 inclusive, not 9999.

Comment: We are not your debugger .... please try to fix by yourself next time!

Comment: @Mcs Please do not edit your question as to destroy its original intent.  It makes this thread unreadable, and is unfair to those who took time to answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are iterating one element beyond the end of the array - change:

```
for (i = 1000; i <=9999 i+=1) {
      name[i] = WERT;
}
```

to

```
for (i = 1000; i < 9999; ++i) {
      name[i] = WERT;
}
```

(or increase the size of `name` to 10000, if you really do need to index up to and including 9999.)

Note also the missing `;`, as pointed out by @jpw, and the more idiomatic usage of `++i` rather than `i+=1`, as noted by @pm100.

Comment: and say i++ not i+=1. It means the same thing but is surprising to see ; makes people think you are trying to do something odd

Comment: @pm100: true, `i++` is more common, but it's not incorrect as it stands.

Comment: sorry I am tired, by the way, i++ might look good in C, but it is disliked in JavaScript, where I come from

Comment: Don't listen to Paul about one thing: `i += 1` is absolutely 100% correct, and a good habit to get into. `++` is a mass of confusion to be avoided at all costs.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: well I didn't say it was *wrong*, just that `i++` is more idiomatic in C (and related languages). You are free to shoot yourself in the foot in as many different ways as you please, of course.

Comment: I agree, it's not "wrong" either way. But when I teach new programmers C, one of the first lessons is "Don't use ++ / --, ever, for any reason, an you will live a long and happy life". I'll also admit that it doesn't bother me nearly as much as Yves' suggestion to move to C++, a whole language named after a bad idea.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: that's an unusual position to take, especially if you are going to collaborate with other programmers, or expect to use C++ as well as C, but each to their own...

Comment: why would you advise people not to use ++ and -- its a commonly used well understood idiom that is in probably every non-trivial c program.

Comment: @pm100 it's just too tempting to use it to make code short, hard to understand, and hard to debug. About twice a week Stackoverflow gets questions about "Why does ++ do this odd thing?"  I stick to the Rodney Dangerfield answer: "Doctor, it hurts when I do this"...Well, don't do that.

Comment: noooo - its must be i++ not ++i ; I guess this shows that Lee is right

Comment: @pm100: `i++` is an abomination and must be cast into hell, `++i` is the One True Increment!

Answer (score 2):

C array indices start at 0, and end at the index one less than the length of the array. You got a SIGSEGV or similar when you tried to write to name[9999] because there is no such array element - and you got lucky and didn't merely overwrite some other object. (Or you did overwrite, and crashed for that reason.)

To fix:

```
for (i = 1000; i <9999 i+=1) {
      name[i] = WERT;
 }
```

For extra style points, don't repeat numeric constants.

Instead

```
#define ARRAY_LEN 9999
float name[ARRAY_LEN];

    for (i = 1000; i < ARRAY_LEN; i+=1) {
          name[i] = WERT;
     }
```

Comment: There's a semi-solon missing between the stop-condition and the increment in the head of the for loop

Comment: Gah! I guess I'm blind ;-) But not sure that fixing compile errors counts as "style" ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Switch to C++ and create a class `WERTSfloat` with a constructor that initializes the value.

```
class WERTSfloat
{
  public:
    float Value;
    WERTSfloat() { Value= WERT; }
};
```

Then

```
WERTSfloat ArrayOf9999WERTSfloats[9999];
```

will fill the whole array, whatever its size :-)

Comment: Haha, where's your sense of humor ?

Comment: That's really horrible for readability. At least call the class Float_array_of_999_WERTS, rather than confusing it with the system data type.

Comment: I guess maybe I'm too tired to get that you were joking^^

Comment: My sense of humour ran off the end of an array and needs to be pulled out of the stack ;-)

Comment: @ArlieStephens: it took me several attempts, now I think I have the proper naming.

Comment: @YvesDaoustYes, that's better. My suggested name was wrong. What you have now is great.